# Programmatic gradient stops with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, hex, gradient

Working with Javascript (jQuery), given 2 color values (`2033ff` and `3300a0` for example) how can I determine certain gradient stops between them?

Reason being is, I intend on using an array of color values:

```
    0 => '000000'
 8400 => 'f0ff00'
44000 => '2033ff'
68400 => '3300a0'
```

There being 86400 seconds in a day, 12:00AM maps to 0, and 11:59PM maps to 86399. As time passes, the background color of a specified element changes to the appropriate color in gradient list via `window.setInterval(function(e){ ... }, 1000)`. For example `2:32:11PM = 52331`, which from the example would be somewhere between `2033ff` and `3300a0`.

I don't need to populate the array with the values (unless that would be easier) but instead use the index and value as references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do a linear interpolation:

Given 2033ff and 3300a0 as start and end you'll do:

```
red1 = 0x2033ff >> 16;
green1 = (0x2033ff >> 8) & 0xFF;
blue1  = 0x2033ff & 0xFF;

red2 = 0x3300a0 >> 16;
green2 = (0x3300a0 >> 8) & 0xFF;
blue2  = 0x3300a0 & 0xFF;

time = 0.3 // This should be between 0 and 1

outred = time * red1 + (1-time) * red2;
outgreen = time * green1 + (1-time) * green2;
outblue = time * blue1 + (1-time) * blue2;
```

Comment: Outstanding **nico**; Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the library [RainbowVis-JS](https://github.com/anomal/RainbowVis-JS) as a general solution for mapping numbers to colours. For your example, you would use:

```
var rainbow = new Rainbow(); 
rainbow.setSpectrum('2033ff', '3300a0');
rainbow.setNumberRange(1, 86400);
var colour = rainbow.colourAt(52331); // 2c14c5
```

Comment: Thanks for the library. I just taught one of our designers how to use it and he loves it. :D