# Get the next and previous element of an array given an index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given I have an array in Javascript, with values as such;

```
0     => 0x0000FF
1200  => 0x00CCFF
28800 => 0xFF0AFF
36000 => 0xFFFFFF
```

How can I determine which elements a given index value falls between? With the previous example, if I have the value 31073, I need to retrieve `28800 => 0xFF0AFF` and `36000 => 0xFFFFFF`

Comment: You mean an associative array? `myarray['0'] = 0x0000FF;` ?

Comment: Would be easy with an object. Much more difficult with an array.

Comment: @Tomcat: Is there a predictable order to the array indices?

Comment: **@stef**; No, numerically indexed. **@Felix Kling**; I was considering that, how would I go about accomplishing that?

Comment: @Felix: How would it be accomplished with an object, given that there's no guaranteed ordering of the properties?

Comment: @patrick dw: A true, I forgot that the ordering is not guaranteed. Ok, then one could do it with a combination of an array and an object (or two arrays). But of course it would still require to loop over (one of) the array(s)...

Comment: @Tomcat: You do have some predictability there. Is that the entire array?

Comment: **@patrick dw**; No, there can be any number of values at any index between 0 and 86399.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to follow up here;

Thanks to both **quixoto** and **patrick dw** for your detailed comments and answers. I have however, gone with a slightly different solution. While I wanted to maintain my initial approach of using a one dimensional array, it's much easier and efficient from what I can see, to add another dimension as shown below. The array used here does exhibit predictability, but that may not be the case once the project is finalized.

```
var colors = [  
    [0,     '121D4A'],
    [10800, '000000'],
    [21600, 'FF5900'],
    [32400, 'D3EEF0'],
    [43200, '7DCDFF'],
    [54000, '7DA6FF'],
    [64800, 'FF5900'],
    [75600, '31428C'],
    [86399, '121D4A'],
];

function gradientStop(color1, color2, gradStop){
    var r = Math.floor(gradStop * parseInt(color2.substr(0, 2), 16) + (1 - gradStop) * parseInt(color1.substr(0, 2), 16)).toString(16);
    var g = Math.floor(gradStop * parseInt(color2.substr(2, 2), 16) + (1 - gradStop) * parseInt(color1.substr(2, 2), 16)).toString(16);
    var b = Math.floor(gradStop * parseInt(color2.substr(4, 2), 16) + (1 - gradStop) * parseInt(color1.substr(4, 2), 16)).toString(16);
    return (r.length < 2 ? '0' + r : r) + (g.length < 2 ? '0' + g : g) + (b.length < 2 ? '0' + b : b);
}

function getColor(colors, currentIndex){
    for(var i = 0, m = colors.length; i < m; i++){
        if(currentIndex >= colors[i][0]){
            if(typeof(colors[i + 1]) !== 'undefined'){
                if(currentIndex <= colors[i + 1][0]){
                    return gradientStop(colors[i][1], colors[i + 1][1], (currentIndex - colors[i][0]) / (colors[i + 1][0] - colors[i][0]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also; Yes **Hemlock** it was an expansion on my question at [Programmatic gradient stops with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580105/programmatic-gradient-stops-with-javascript), hence the `gradientStop()` function.

Comment: +1 That looks good. Sort of a hybrid between your original, and @quixoto's solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "built-in" way to accomplish this with Javascript's sparse arrays. The simplest way  to do this for arbitrary sparse indexes while maintaining some efficiency is to keep another lookaside sorted array of the indexes into the main array. Then you can walk the lookaside list to find the right neighbor indexes, and go back to the main array to get their values.

If your array will be huge or accesses need to be faster than O(items), you could look into various tree structures for the lookaside object.

Comment: **@quixoto**; The array won't be huge per se. The maximum possible indexed value is 86399, however there will only be about 10 to 20 values with indices between 0 and 86399.

Comment: @TomcatExodus You don't have to worry about efficiency if you are simply building on the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580105/programmatic-gradient-stops-with-javascript; Just fill out the array once and then index into it from then on.

Comment: @TomcatExodus: If there are only 10-20 values altogether, then looping through them is trivial performance wise. Keep a separate list with those 10-20 values. Find the nearest ones of those, and then use them as indexes back into the main array.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way that simply uses a couple `while()` loops with no body.

It assumes the starting point will always be in between. You'll need a couple of quick additional tests if that's not the case.

Also, I wasn't sure what should happen if the starting point is directly on a color, so I didn't account for that.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tcVxP/4/

```
var num = 31234,
    curr = num,
    prev,
    next;

while( !colors[--curr] && curr );
prev = colors[curr];

curr = num;
while( !colors[++curr] );
next = colors[curr];
```

Comment: A note on this technique: its performance is linear in the size of the overall possible range of values, since it walks every possible index to find the adjacent one with a value. Be a little careful if you need to call this frequently or need it to be super fast. Also, a bug: because the test isn't a strict test for `undefined`, if the value at an real neighbor index is zero or something else falsy, you won't find it.

Comment: @quixoto: You're right about walking every index, though it should be quick since there's no body to the `while` statement. Your idea in your comment about keeping a separate list is a good one. You should add it to your answer. With regard to the bug, that's true, except that I'm working under the assumption that the Array in the question is accurate in that index `0` has the only falsey value. As such, it is covered with the `&& curr` part of the first `while`. Unfortunately we don't really have the full picture in the question.

Comment: That *is* my answer-- apparently it's not as clearly written as it could be. :) FWIW, walking every index is O(n) regardless of how much work you do during the loop, but agree that without more detail, it's hard to know what's worth optimizing for.

Comment: @quixoto: Sorry, I just took a very quick look, and must have paid more attention to the comment. +1 on your solution.